# Set batch/split size of Scala parallel collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am using parallel sequence where the computation is done on a single item is not large enough to justify the context switching and overhead of running it on a separate thread. Instead, I would like to split the collection into 16 parts, or into batches of 1000 items, and run those in parallel. Is it possible?

Comment: On the JVM you would need to run your computation on multiple threads to obtain "parallel" computation. You can use a thread pool to avoid some of the overhead. (In particular, the [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) executor service sounds like it _might_ be useful for your task.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can use here are Parallel Collections. If you already do you can configure their behavior.

From the Documentation:

> There are currently a few task support implementations available for parallel collections. The ForkJoinTaskSupport uses a fork-join pool internally

See here 
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html

Comment: The parallel collections use `ForkJoinPool`, which Lars mentioned, and that class is smart about not using too many threads. Instead of trying to second-guess it by breaking your data into batches yourself, you should just trust the parallel collections to handle it for you.

Comment: The parallel collection works by splitting the data into batches and dividing them between the threads. My question is how to make these batches bigger.

Comment: The point is: pick an algorithm (e.g. ForkJoinPool) and then let the JVM pick the optimal execution plan. If you think you can beat the JVM then I'd suggest choosing a lower level language than Scala.